# Send manually request to GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I want to send manually requests to a graphql server using Apollo,

Actually Im wrapping my App in an ApolloProvider and the requests are send each time I render my component. Here is the code of my component :

```
export default graphql(gql`
  query Hello{
        hello
        }
  `)(myComponent);
```

How may I send the graphql requests manually without passing by the component rendering (handled by buttons clicks for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apollo-fetch](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-fetch) to run standalone graphql queries that integrate with your Apollo store.

Comment: I m using apollo-fetch actually and I like it .. it gives me more controle on staff